# Set Default Database connection Mysql Workbench 5.2

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to set a default connection when forward engineering, synchronizing, etc. with MySQL Workbench. I am not sure if this is possible but it would save me some extra clicks. If it can be done on a per model basis that would be excellent. I searched their documentation but could not find it.

Comment: I'd like to know if this possible too, would be nice if the whole forward engineering could be automated...

Answer (score 11):

Well, the closest solution I use is to doubleclick the preferred database in schema list.